# How could I make my Simulator buttons appear?

Tags: java, oop, button

The buttons originally do appear in my original code (which I have not refactored):

```
package oose.vcs;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import vehicle.types.Airplane;
import vehicle.types.Bicycle;
import vehicle.types.Boat;
import vehicle.types.Bus;
import vehicle.types.Car;
import vehicle.types.Helicopter;
import vehicle.types.Motorcycle;
import vehicle.types.Ship;
import vehicle.types.Train;
import vehicle.types.Tram;
import vehicle.types.Truck;
import vehicle.types.Vehicle;


public class Controller {

    private Vehicle vehicle;
    private String[] vehicles = { "Boat", "Ship", "Truck", "Motorcycle", "Bus", "Car", "Bicycle", "Helicopter", "Airplane", "Tram", "Train"};
    private Simulator simulationPane;
    private JLabel speedlabel;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JButton button4;
    private JButton button5;
    private JComboBox<String> combobox;
    private JFrame frame;

    private boolean accelerate, decelerate, cruise,stop;
    int currentvelocity = 1;
    int maximumvelocity = 300;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Controller();
    }

    public Controller() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                frame = new JFrame("Vehicle Control System");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                combobox = new JComboBox<String>(vehicles);
                combobox.setSelectedIndex(6);
                combobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int selectedIndex = combobox.getSelectedIndex();
                        String vehicleName = vehicles[selectedIndex];
                        initialiseVehicle(vehicleName);                         
                    }
                });

                speedlabel = new JLabel("          ");
                
                configStart();
                configAccelerate();
                configDecelerate();
                configCruise();
                configStop();
                
                JToolBar toolBar =new JToolBar();
                toolBar.setRollover(true);

                toolBar.add(combobox);
                toolBar.add(speedlabel);
                toolBar.add(button1);
                toolBar.add(button2);
                toolBar.add(button3);
                toolBar.add(button4);
                toolBar.add(button5);

                frame.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,200));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
    
    private void configStart() {
        button1 = new JButton("start");
        button1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(vehicle == null) {
                    int selectedIndex = combobox.getSelectedIndex();
                    String vehicleName = vehicles[selectedIndex];
                    initialiseVehicle(vehicleName);
                    speedlabel.setText(vehicle.printSpeed());
                }
                if(simulationPane !=null) {
                    frame.remove(simulationPane);
                }
                accelerate = false;
                decelerate = false;
                cruise = false;
                stop = false;
                button1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                button2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button3.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button4.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button5.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

                simulationPane = new Simulator();
                frame.add(simulationPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }

        });
    }

    private void configAccelerate() {
        button2 = new JButton("accelerate");
        button2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                accelerate = true;
                decelerate = false;
                cruise = false;
                stop = false;

                button1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button2.setBackground(Color.green);
                button3.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button4.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button5.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

                Thread thread = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            while(accelerate) {
                                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);

                                if(currentvelocity<=maximumvelocity) {
                                    currentvelocity = currentvelocity +1;
                                    vehicle.setCurrentSpeed(currentvelocity);
                                    speedlabel.setText(vehicle.printSpeed());
                                    simulationPane.updateTimer();
                                }                                       
                            }
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    }
                };

                thread.start();
            }                       
        });

    }
    
    private void configCruise() {
        button3 = new JButton("cruise");
        button3.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                accelerate = false;
                decelerate = false;
                cruise = true;
                stop = false;

                button1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button3.setBackground(Color.green);
                button4.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button5.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

            }                       
        });
    }
    private void configDecelerate() {
        button4 = new JButton("decelerate");
        button4.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                accelerate = false;
                decelerate = true;
                cruise = false;
                stop = false;

                button1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button3.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button4.setBackground(Color.green);
                button5.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                
                Thread thread = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try {
                            while(decelerate) {
                                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);

                                if(currentvelocity >1) {
                                    currentvelocity = currentvelocity -1;
                                    vehicle.setCurrentSpeed(currentvelocity);
                                    speedlabel.setText(vehicle.printSpeed());
                                    simulationPane.updateTimer();
                                }                                       
                            }
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    }
                };

                thread.start();
            }                       
        });
    }
    
    private void configStop() {
        button5 = new JButton("stop");
        button5.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                accelerate = false;
                decelerate = false;
                cruise = false;
                stop = true;

                button1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button3.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button4.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                button5.setBackground(Color.green);
                
                currentvelocity = 1;
                vehicle.setCurrentSpeed(currentvelocity);
                speedlabel.setText(vehicle.printSpeed());
                simulationPane.updateTimer();
            }                       
        });
    }
    
    private void initialiseVehicle(String vehicleName) {
        if(vehicleName.equals("Boat")) {
            vehicle = new Boat("Apollo ");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Ship")) {
            vehicle = new Ship("Cruizz");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Truck")) {
            vehicle = new Truck("Ford F-650");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Motorcycle")) {
            vehicle = new Motorcycle("Suzuki");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Bus")) {
            vehicle = new Bus("Aero");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Car")) {
            vehicle = new Car("BMW");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Bicycle")) {
            vehicle = new Bicycle("A-bike");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Helicopter")) {
            vehicle = new Helicopter("Eurocopter");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Airplane")) {
            vehicle = new Airplane("BA");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Tram")) {
            vehicle = new Tram("EdinburghTram");
        }
        else if(vehicleName.equals("Train")) {
            vehicle = new Train("Virgin",4);
        }       
    }


    public class Simulator extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage boat;
        private int xPos = 0;
        private int direction = 1;
        private File file; 
        private Timer timer;
        public Simulator() {
            setDisplayObject();
            try {   
                boat = ImageIO.read(file);
                timer = new Timer(maximumvelocity/currentvelocity, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        xPos += direction;
                        if (xPos + boat.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                            xPos = 0;
                            direction *= -1;

                        } else if (xPos < 0) { 
                            xPos = 0;
                            direction *= -1;
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }

                });
                timer.setRepeats(true);
                timer.setCoalesce(true);
                timer.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void updateTimer() {
            timer.setDelay(maximumvelocity/currentvelocity);
        }

        private void setDisplayObject() {
            if(vehicle instanceof Boat) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/boat.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Ship) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/ship.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Truck) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/truck.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Motorcycle) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/motorcycle.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Bus) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/bus.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Car) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/car.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Bicycle) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/bicycle.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Helicopter) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/helicopter.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Airplane) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/airplane.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Tram) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/tram.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Train) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/train.png");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return boat == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(boat.getWidth() * 4, boat.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int y = getHeight() - boat.getHeight();
            g.drawImage(boat, xPos, y, this);

        }

    }

}
```

However, after refactoring the buttons, they no longer appear on the simulator:

```
package oose.vcs;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import vehicle.types.Airplane;
import vehicle.types.Bicycle;
import vehicle.types.Boat;
import vehicle.types.Bus;
import vehicle.types.Car;
import vehicle.types.Helicopter;
import vehicle.types.Motorcycle;
import vehicle.types.Ship;
import vehicle.types.Train;
import vehicle.types.Tram;
import vehicle.types.Truck;
import vehicle.types.Vehicle;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;




public class Controller {



    enum ButtonState {
        Start,
        Accelerate,
        Cruise,
        Decelerate,
        Stop;
    }

    static Vehicle vehicle;
    static String[] vehicles = { "Boat", "Ship", "Truck", "Motorcycle", "Bus", "Car", "Bicycle", "Helicopter", "Airplane", "Tram", "Train"};
    private Simulator simulationPane;
    private JLabel speedlabel;

    private JComboBox<String> combobox;
    private JFrame frame;
    
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private ButtonState state;

    private boolean accelerate, decelerate;
    static int currentvelocity = 1;
    static int maximumvelocity = 300;
    
    static String vehicleName;
    static int selectedIndex;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Controller();
    }

    public Controller() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                frame = new JFrame("Vehicle Control System");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                combobox = new JComboBox<String>(vehicles);
                combobox.setSelectedIndex(6);
                combobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int selectedIndex = combobox.getSelectedIndex();
                        vehicleName = vehicles[selectedIndex];
                        initialiseVehicle(vehicleName);                         
                    }
                });

                speedlabel = new JLabel("          ");
                
                configButtons();
                
                JToolBar toolBar =new JToolBar();
                toolBar.setRollover(true);

                toolBar.add(combobox);
                toolBar.add(speedlabel);


                frame.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,200));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
    
    

    

    private void setState(ButtonState state) {
        this.buttons[this.state.ordinal()].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        this.buttons[state.ordinal()].setBackground(Color.green);
        this.state = state;
    }

    private void configButtons() {
        this.buttons = new JButton[ButtonState.values().length];
        
        for (ButtonState state : ButtonState.values()) {
            JButton button = new JButton(state.name().toLowerCase());
            button.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            
            switch(state) {
                case Start: 
                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            start(e);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                        
                case Accelerate: 
                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            accelerate(e);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                    
                case Cruise: 
                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            cruise(e);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                        
                case Decelerate:
                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            decelerate(e);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                    
                case Stop:
                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            stop(e);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
            
            this.buttons[state.ordinal()] = button;
        }
    }

    private void start(ActionEvent e) {
        if(vehicle == null) {
            selectedIndex = combobox.getSelectedIndex();
            String vehicleName = vehicles[selectedIndex];
            initialiseVehicle(vehicleName);
            speedlabel.setText(vehicle.printSpeed());
        }
        
        if(simulationPane !=null) {
            frame.remove(simulationPane);
        }
        
        this.setState(ButtonState.Start);

        simulationPane = new Simulator();
        frame.add(simulationPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    private void accelerate(ActionEvent e) {
        this.setState(ButtonState.Accelerate);

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    while(accelerate) {
                        Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);

                        if(currentvelocity<=maximumvelocity) {
                            currentvelocity = currentvelocity +1;
                            vehicle.setCurrentSpeed(currentvelocity);
                            speedlabel.setText(vehicle.printSpeed());
                            simulationPane.updateTimer();
                        }                                       
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }

    private void cruise(ActionEvent e) {
        this.setState(ButtonState.Cruise);
    }

    private void decelerate(ActionEvent e) {
        this.setState(ButtonState.Decelerate);
        
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    while(decelerate) {
                        Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);

                        if(currentvelocity >1) {
                            currentvelocity = currentvelocity -1;
                            vehicle.setCurrentSpeed(currentvelocity);
                            speedlabel.setText(vehicle.printSpeed());
                            simulationPane.updateTimer();
                        }                                       
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }

    private void stop(ActionEvent e) {
       this.setState(ButtonState.Stop);
        
        currentvelocity = 1;
        vehicle.setCurrentSpeed(currentvelocity);
        speedlabel.setText(vehicle.printSpeed());
        simulationPane.updateTimer();
    }
    
    


    public void initialiseVehicle(String vehicleName){ 
      
       // Create a hashmap with key value pairs
        Map<String,Vehicle> objectMap = new HashMap<String, Vehicle>();
        
        // Add all the items into this map
        objectMap.put("Airplane",new Airplane("BA"));
        objectMap.put("Tram",new Tram("EdinburghTram"));
        objectMap.put("Train",new Train("Virgin",4));
        objectMap.put("Helicopter",new Helicopter("Eurocopter"));
        objectMap.put("Bicycle",new Bicycle("A-bike"));
        objectMap.put("Car",new Car("BMW"));
        objectMap.put("Bus",new Bus("Aero"));
        objectMap.put("Motorcycle",new Motorcycle("Suzuki"));
        objectMap.put("Truck",new Truck("Ford F-650"));
        objectMap.put("Ship",new Ship("Cruizz"));
        objectMap.put("Boat", new Boat("Apollo"));

        // checks if the item exist in the map
        if(objectMap.containsKey(vehicleName)){ 
            vehicle = objectMap.get(vehicleName);
        }

    }

    
    
    private class Simulator extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8809852587026347126L;
        private BufferedImage boat;
        private int xPos = 0;
        private int direction = 1;
        protected File file; 
        private Timer timer;
        public Simulator() {
            setDisplayObject();
            try {   
                boat = ImageIO.read(file);
                timer = new Timer(Controller.maximumvelocity/Controller.currentvelocity, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        xPos += direction;
                        if (xPos + boat.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                            xPos = 0;
                            direction *= -1;

                        } else if (xPos < 0) { 
                            xPos = 0;
                            direction *= -1;
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }

                });
                timer.setRepeats(true);
                timer.setCoalesce(true);
                timer.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void updateTimer() {
            timer.setDelay(Controller.maximumvelocity/Controller.currentvelocity);
        }
        

        private void setDisplayObject() {   
            if(vehicle instanceof Boat) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/boat.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Ship) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/ship.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Truck) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/truck.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Motorcycle) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/motorcycle.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Bus) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/bus.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Car) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/car.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Bicycle) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/bicycle.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Helicopter) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/helicopter.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Airplane) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/airplane.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Tram) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/tram.png");
            }
            else if(vehicle instanceof Train) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/img/train.png");
            }
            
            
        }

        
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return boat == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(boat.getWidth() * 4, boat.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int y = getHeight() - boat.getHeight();
            g.drawImage(boat, xPos, y, this);

        }
        



    }
    
    
}
```

May I ask what could have gone wrong and how I could modify my refactored code?

Here are example of what the vehicle classes look like (essentially `getters` and `setters`):

```
package vehicle.types;

public abstract class Aircraft extends Vehicle{
    private double steering;
    
    public Aircraft(String name) {
        setName(name);
        setType(Type.SKIED);
    }

            
    @Override
    public void streer(double degree, double speed) {
        setCurrentSpeed(speed);
        setSteering(degree);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String printSpeed() {
        return getCurrentSpeed()+"km/hr";
    }

    public double getSteering() {
        return steering;
    }


    public void setSteering(double degrees) {
        this.steering = degrees;
    }
}
```

```
package vehicle.types;

public class Airplane extends Aircraft {

    public Airplane(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original code you were adding the buttons to the toolbar

```
toolBar.add(button1);
toolBar.add(button2);
toolBar.add(button3);
...
```

But in the refactored code you don't do that anymore. I guess you could add them in `configButtons()` while you are looping through them.